# Analysis method for two-way slab floor with central column

Tags: structural-analysis, reinforced-concrete

What method would be appropriate to analyze this concrete structure? 
A two-way rectangular concrete slab with walls and central column.

I would like to understand how to model it with either yield line method or equivalent frame method. Or both to be honest.

I'm studying those methods at introductory level, but haven't found any example of a similar case, so unsure how to draw out the analytical models.

[image]

Comment: Your drawing is not clear. Are those load bearing walls or invisible columns? That is critical to understanding what method needs to be used

Comment: @Rhodie Yes intention was for walls to be load bearing.

Comment: I'll have a look at my textbooks which deal with this. Maybe I'll have an answer soon